# How to Write Extension Method for RedirectToAction To Set TempData In Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i want to write an extension method for RedirectToAction() Method that is called in mvc controller. in this method i want to set **TempData** with my message and have something like this     **RedirectToAction("Index").WithMessage(message)**

i wrote this code

```
    public static class ActionResultExtension
{
    public static IActionResult WithMessage(this IActionResult result,string message)
    {

    }
}
```

but the problem is that i don't know how should i have access to the context

Comment: Your current approach is trying to call the proposed `WithMessage` extension method on the `RedirectToRouteResult` object. Instead of that, how about creating a wrapper method in your base controller which sets the TempData and then do the redirect ?

Comment: you are right but RedirectToRouteResult  is inherited from IActionResult...i heard from someone that i can use decorator pattern for this purpose but i don't know how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting Question :)

The intial solution would be to implement a custom `ActionResult` which would override `ExecuteResult` method to set the `TempData` message.

**Create Custom ActionResult:**
`

```
public class RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly string message;

    public RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult(ActionResult redirectBaseResult, string message)
    {
        BaseResult = redirectBaseResult;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ActionResult BaseResult { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.Controller.TempData["Message.Notification"] = this.message;

        BaseResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

**Create Extention Methods**

```
public static class RedirectExtensions
{
    public static RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult WithConfirmation(this RedirectToRouteResult instance, string message)
    {
        return new RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult(instance, message);
    }

    public static RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult WithConfirmation(this RedirectResult instance, string message)
    {
        return new RedirectWithConfirmationMessageResult(instance, message);
    }        
}
```

**Usage**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    return this
        .RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        .WithConfirmation("Saved Successfully !");
}
```

Hope helps.

Credits goes to author of [this](https://sergeyakopov.com/extending-asp-net-mvc-redirects-with-confirmations/) post.

Comment: i've got two problems with this solution ...first i don't have access to Controller in context.Controller and another is i get this error 'no suitable methode found to override'...by the way i am using asp.net core 2.1

Comment: @Abolfazl  if you are using  `asp.net core` then why you have added `asp.net mvc` as your tag ? Currently your questions will reach folks who know `asp.net mvc` , please update your tag if you need the answer.

Comment: @Abolfazl You are welcome :) , I guess this code should work in `asp.net core` too. I think you are getting run time error , if you could add code  about your action methods etc , others can help you.